# Strange behaviour of ww SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

Can anyone explain why do I get those values while trying to parse a date?
I've tried three different inputs, as follows:

1) Third week of 2013

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("ww.yyyy").parse("02.2013");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + "." + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Which outputs: `02.2013` (as I expected)

2) First week of 2013

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("ww.yyyy").parse("00.2013");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + "." + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Which outputs: `52.2012` (which is fine for me, since the first week of 2013 is also the last one of 2012)

3) Second week of 2013

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("ww.yyyy").parse("01.2013");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + "." + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Which outputs: `1.2012` (which makes absolutely **no** sense to me)

Does anyone know why this happens?? I need to parse a date in the format (week of year).(year). Am I using the wrong pattern?

Comment: Tip: Considering altering your week-of-year format to follow the non-ambiguous format defined by the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) standard. Like this: `2014-W19`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library could then help you parse and generate such strings using its formatters built into the [ISODateTimeFormat](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) factory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're using `ww`, which is "week of week-year", but then `yyyy` which is "calendar year" rather than "week year". Setting the week-of-week-year and then setting the calendar year is a recipe for problems, because they're just separate numbering systems, effectively.

You should be using `YYYY` in your format string to specify the week-year... although unfortunately it looks like you can't then *get* the value in a sane way. (I'd expect a `Calendar.WEEKYEAR` constant, but there is no such thing.)

Also, week-of-year values start at 1, not 0... and no week is in two week-years; it's *either* the first week of 2013 *or* it's the last week of 2012... it's not both.

I would personally avoid using week-years and weeks if you possibly can - they can be very confusing, particularly when a date in one calendar year is in a different week year.

Comment: Thanks, now I realize the reason why there's yyyy and YYYY

Comment: The problem (as you mentioned) is that I can't get the value of the week-year (and I need it, I'm just parsing the string to validate it). Should I post another question in order to see if someone knows how can I do it?

Comment: @fvdalcin: Yes, post another question - but explain what your actual situation is. Does your idea of "weeks of year" even align with what `java.util.Calendar` does? You might also want to consider using Joda Time, which not only makes this information available, but is also a better date/time API in every respect.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Calendar.getWeekYear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getWeekYear%28%29) to get year value synced with `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` field.
There is more information about Week of Year and Week Year at the [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) doc.