# Confusing Java week format for "20151227"

Tags: java, date, format

When I try to format `20151227` to week by pattern `yyyyww`, I got result `201501` which really confused me. I thought it would be `201601`.

Then I format `201601` to day by pattern `yyyyMMdd`, I got `20151227`. So weird.

Here is the full code:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

    public static String format(Date d, String format) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(d);
    }

    public static Date parse(String t, String format) throws ParseException {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(t);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(format(parse("20151227", "yyyyMMdd"), "yyyyww"));// The console prints "201501"

        System.out.println(format(parse("201601", "yyyyww"), "yyyyMMdd"));//prints "20151227"
    }
}
```

Comment: It formattes only long numbers

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23542216/1743880 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6754024/1743880

Comment: `LocalDate.parse( "20151227" , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE )`. For weeks, use standard [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) and the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class from [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library. Never use `Date` or `SimpleDateFormat` classes, outmoded by JSR 310.